# is there a way to bring text over a "before" pseudo element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to html and css in general, but am trying to get the header and paragraph text above the gradient background, so it's more legible. I'm sure there is something simple i'm missing, and any help is appreciated :)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/minacosentino/pen/YxLLQw

```
.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fc981de707eb954cdcfca3/t/572a8a8d37013b0bab651c88/1462405784417/business+working+unsplash.com.jpg?format=1500w');
  height: 40rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  position: relative;
}

.jumbotron::before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -webkit-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -moz-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -o-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to give your `.container` element a non-static positioning, and it will naturally come to the front.

Right now, your `.jumbotron::before` is set to `position: absolute`, and because the `.container` (its sibling) has no non-static positioning defined, it's showing up behind it.

I've added this to the end of your CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Working demo:

```css
.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fc981de707eb954cdcfca3/t/572a8a8d37013b0bab651c88/1462405784417/business+working+unsplash.com.jpg?format=1500w');
  height: 40rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  position: relative;
}

.container {}

.jumbotron::before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -webkit-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203, 67, 152, .7) 0%, rgba(100, 190, 235, .7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -moz-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203, 67, 152, .7) 0%, rgba(100, 190, 235, .7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -o-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203, 67, 152, .7) 0%, rgba(100, 190, 235, .7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(203, 67, 152, .7) 0%, rgba(100, 190, 235, .7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,500" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>hello!</h2>
    <p>welcome to inside sales</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Jon- do you happen to know why my .jumbotron p isn't formatting either? i've been trying to change the size, but it won't alter.... again, thanks for your help + expertise!

Answer (score 0):

you can give z-index value to before pesudo element

```
   .jumbotron::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -webkit-linear-gradient(to top right, 
    rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -moz-linear-gradient(to top right, 
    rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -o-linear-gradient(to top right, 
    rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to top right, 
    rgba(203,67,152,.7) 0%, rgba(100,190,235,.7) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
    }
```

Comment: This does not achieve the desired result, and hides the gradient.

Comment: you can give z-index to your container as well <pre>.jumbotron .container
{
  z-index:999999;
}

Answer (score 0):

I used `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);`

I have an structure like this:

```
.blog-header {
  position: relative;
  ...
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../static/shape.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }

  &__breadcrumb {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    ...
  }
}
```

Or

```
.blog-header {
  position: relative;
...
}
.blog-header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../static/shape.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.blog-header__breadcrumb {
  ...
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use can use z-index property in css to change the layer an element is displayed on.

[z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
.jumbotron container {
    z-index: 2000;
}
```